# count the total numbers of unique letters occurred once in a string in python?

Tags: python

```
a = 'abhishek'
count = 0

for x in a:
    if x in a:
        count += 1 
print(count)
```

I have tried this but it gives me the total number of letters. I want only a unique latter that occurs only once.

Comment: Why did you imagine that code would do otherwise?

Comment: `x in a` is true for all `x` in `a`, so you end up calculating the number of characters in the string that... are in this string

Comment: `count = sum(v for v in Counter(a).values() if v == 1)`

Answer (score 5):

`len(set(a))` will give you the unique count of letters

Edit: add explanation

`set(a)` returns a container of all the unique characters (Python calls this the `set`) in the string `a`. Then `len()` gets the count of that set, which corresponds to the count of unique chars in string `a`.

Comment: Could you give a bit more explanations as to why it works?

Comment: @CorentinPane `set(a)` returns a container of all the unique characters (Python calls this the `set`) in the string `a`. Then `len()` gets the count of that set, which corresponds to the count of unique chars in string `a`.

Comment: I meant, could you please edit your answer and put this in your answer.

Comment: have you read the question? "count the characters that appear only __once__", `len(set(...))` counts every character no matter how many times it appears.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating the string and checking the letter in the string itself, so your `if condition is always True` in this case.

What you need is to maintain a separate list of all the letters you have already seen while iterating the string. Like this,

```
uniq_list = []
a = 'abhishek'
count = 0

for x in a:
    if x not in uniq_list: # check if the letter is already seen.
        count += 1 # increase the counter only when the letter is not seen.
        uniq_list.append(x) # add the letter in the list to mark it as seen.
print(count)
```

Comment: For long strings, making `uniq_list` a `set` would be more efficient.

Comment: @chepner  Yes, I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'abhishek'
count = 0
uls = set()
nls = set()
for x in a:
    if x not in uls:
        uls.add(x)
    else:
        nls.add(x)

print(len(uls - nls))
```

> it will print char, which occur only once.

Output: 6

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

`a = 'abhishek'
a.count('a') # or any other letter you want to count.`

> 1

Is this what you want?